# Checking step by step proof of $\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt2-\sqrt[n]2)^n=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, solution-verification

$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {(\sqrt 2  - \root n \of 2 )^n}$$

Is it right to say:
the limit of $\sqrt2$ is $\sqrt2$
the limit of $\root n \of 2$ is 1

then, $\sqrt2 - 1$ is between 0 to 1.
so, the limit of $(\sqrt2 - 1)^n $ must be 0.

in conclusion,
$$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty } {(\sqrt 2  - \root n \of 2 )^n} = 0$$

is it right?

Comment: The limit should be as $n \to \infty$, not $x \to \infty$, no?

Comment: yes. I'll change (it's a typo)

Comment: I suggested the edit, you could just wait.

Comment: Yes, it is right. A small point: It is important to emphasize in the proof, that the limit of $\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[n]{2}$ is not $1$. If it were $1$ then more work would be needed to determine the limit of $(\sqrt{2}-\sqrt[n]{2})^n$

Comment: Note that you do not even need that $\sqrt[n]2$ converges. It is enough to note that $0\le \sqrt 2-\sqrt[n]2<\frac12$ and then the seuqnce is squeezed between $0^n$ and $\frac1{2^n}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works just fine and is perfectly rigorous, once you take ABC's comment into consideration.

Comment: so, should I prove $\sqrt 2 - 1$ is between 0-1, or is it an overkill?

Comment: Overkill. Just state it, but don't forget to make the remark that it is necessary.